# google chrome replay XHR request but it send without form data

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-devtools

In DevTools in Chrome I use "replay XHR" command. It send new request but WITHOUT Form Data. Original XHR request contains Form Data.
This issue happend after I updated my Chorme.
I use Chrome version 34.0.1847.116
Maybe I need to do some settings?

Comment: I just observed the same behavior, seems like a nasty bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final comment in this Chromium Bug Ticket says: The patch was landed for M35, so issue should be fixed in beta channel - as of April 14, 2014.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=353921

Comment: I came here because I have the same problem with Chrome 66